# Advice on CRM Integration with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a requirement from a client to integrate with their customer/warranty database using a REST Api. The client sells mobile phones and needs to manage warranties through this system.

However the software company providing the API is insisting that we should not use Magento's customer account system in favour of using theirs via an API. Basically removing all functionality relating to customer accounts in Magento and fetching all data with REST API Requests.

My preferred solution is to only query their API when required and sync data between like a usual CRM integration.

Please could I have some opinions as to if this is a good/bad idea? and why?
What is best practise and reasons why I can push back basically.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a few years to spend replacing the native Magento customer modules and all associated functionality (login, sessions, registration, promotional rules, tiered pricing, checkout, wishlists ... ie. everything in Magento) - then using their API would be just fine.

Otherwise, I can't see how you would be able to retain any Magento functionality if you stopped using `Mage_Customer`. Even if you emulated the model's getter/setter methods - how would you account for table joins/queries outside of the scope of a pure `getModel('customer/customer')->load()`

There are thousands of downsides and not a single positive of doing this ...

- They go down, you go down
- Internet between you and them has an issue, you go down
- Their API is slow, you are slow
- Loss of entire native Magento functionality
- Nigh on all 3rd party modules are unlikely to function
- ...

Real-time API always scares me because the performance overheads and stability risk is just far too high. I much prefer background API activity that is asynchronous to the user's activity (ie. queued changes to remote, scheduled pulls to local copy).

Keeping data local does mean you have to account for possible sync issues, but would allow far faster performance (with no overhead), and would allow the other API to go down and for the store to still continue to function.

Answer (score 0):

I have once developed an integration where we had the customers table on a CRM.
I and my team have developed the integration like that:

1- Import all customers into Magento (not all data, just the required ones). We had set up webhooks on customer's CRM to recall our API when a customer was modified/created and also a scheduled batch at night to align customers.

2- In order to let their users log-in to our Magento, we have created a custom module to allow login without password. Basically, we generated dynamically an OTP (One Time Password) we passed to the customer's CRM during the data alignment.

3- On customer's CRM they have added a button to call our custom login method, passing username and OTP, so that the customer thinks he has transparent login to Magento, without inserting password.

I hope this gives you an idea.